# Loop thru object to output icons javascript

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, for-in-loop

Sorry for the poor title–I didn't know what to put.
Anyways, I have this object I want to loop thru in order to dynamically output some icons onclick:

```html
<button id="btn">hit me</button>
```

```js
var socialMedia = {
    facebook: "http://facebook.com",
    twitter: "http://twitter.com",
    instagram: "http://instagram.com",
    dribbble: "http://dribbble.com",
    social: function() {
        var output = "<ul>";
        var myList = document.querySelectorAll('.socialSpot');

        for (var key in arguments[0]) {
            output += '<li><a href="' + this[key] + '"><img src="_assets/' 
                   + key + '.png" alt="' + key + 'icon"></a></li>';
        }

        output += '</ul>';

        for (var i = myList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            myList[i].innerHTML = output;
        };
    }
};

var theBtn = document.getElementById('btn');
theBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    socialMedia.social(socialMedia);
}, false);
```

I know I could remove the method and instantiate it while passing the object, but I was wondering how I could go about it this way. In other words, I want to leave the function as a method of the socialMedia {}. Any pointers?

Comment: Why not just make a `data` subproperty that contains the map?

Comment: I agree with @Bergi - mixing logic and data like this is suspect, at best. Separation of concerns, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `if (typeof obj[key] != "string") continue;` test to your loop:

```
…
social: function(obj) {
    var output = "<ul>";
    var myList = document.querySelectorAll('.socialSpot');

    for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof this[key] != "string") continue;
        output += '<li><a href="' + this[key] + '"><img src="_assets/' 
               + key + '.png" alt="' + key + 'icon"></a></li>';
    }

    output += '</ul>';

    for (var i = myList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        myList[i].innerHTML = output;
    };
}
```

---

Of course, simply using another object would be so much cleaner:

```
var socialMedia = {
    data: {
        facebook: "http://facebook.com",
        twitter: "http://twitter.com",
        instagram: "http://instagram.com",
        dribbble: "http://dribbble.com"
    },
    social: function(obj) {
        var data = obj || this.data;

        var output = "<ul>";
        for (var key in data) {
            output += '<li><a href="' + data[key] + '"><img src="_assets/' 
                   + key + '.png" alt="' + key + 'icon"></a></li>';
        }
        output += '</ul>';

        var myList = document.querySelectorAll('.socialSpot');
        for (var i = myList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            myList[i].innerHTML = output;
        };
    }
};

var theBtn = document.getElementById('btn');
theBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    socialMedia.social();
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, Bergi. This answered a number of questions

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass in socialMedia to have access to the socialMedia object inside of the social function. As the social function's execution context is socialMedia's execution context, `this` will be bound to socialMedia inside of social. In other words

```
var socialMedia = {
 ...
 social: function(){
  var socialMedia = this;
  //socialMedia.facebook == this.facebook
  //socialMedia.twitter == this.twitter
  //you can loop through this inside of for in to get these properties 
  //(although you may want to make sure to avoid the function again)
 }
};
```

`this` will be available no matter what, so you can call `socialMedia.social()` without any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with an easier API and still keep both together (without having them both together)

```
var socialMedias = (function() {

    var medias = {
        facebook: "http://facebook.com",
        twitter: "http://twitter.com",
        instagram: "http://instagram.com",
        dribbble: "http://dribbble.com",
    };

    return function(socials) {

        if (!socials) {
            return medias;
        }

        var output = "<ul>";
        var myList = document.querySelectorAll('.socialSpot');

        for (var key in socials) {
            output += '<li><a href="' + this[key] + '"><img src="_assets/' 
                   + key + '.png" alt="' + key + 'icon"></a></li>';
        }

        output += '</ul>';

        for (var i = myList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            myList[i].innerHTML = output;
        };
    };


})();
```

So `socialMedias()` return the map, individual entry can be fetched like `socialMedias().facebook` and `socialMedias(myArgument)` would run the method

Comment: Why make it that ugly? A function should only have a single purpose, and not do completely different things depending on whether an argument is given or not.

Comment: OP didn't ask for a clean way of doing it, otherwise it would have used 2 objects and do it the normal way. As for function with a single purpose go tell that to jQuery too ;)